# How to link Dialogflow CX agent to GCP Project Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to link Dialogflow CX agent with service account on Google Cloud Platform console.
This is for connecting my Dialogflow CX agent to node-red scenario. When I did it with Dialogflow ES it worked just fine. But with Dialogflow CX I just can't seem to get this moving.

I found similar error solved here: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/issues/33

But I don't get how they linked and solved it..

What I did are..

1. I created new project on Dialogflow CX and a new agent.
2. Then I get into Google Cloud console and connect to the new project. There, under IAM and administrator section there's Service Account page. There is nothing.
3. So I create a new service account and also create JSON key file.
4. Now when I go back to Dialogflow CX console and see Share page in Agent Settings, I see the service account I just made on GCP console.

But I still get the error message as follows:
"Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'divine-course-354701'."

If anybody has a clue please let me know. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have used the Dialogflow CX console to create the Agent, then there is a Google Cloud project that is created behind the scenes for you and you have to work with that Project.
2. Each Google Cloud Project has a Name and a Project ID. You should use the Project Id. To get the Google Cloud Project Id for your Agent, go to the Project dropdown list at the top of the console and select view all projects. You will see the specify Project Name and Project Id. Make sure that you are working with the Project Id because that is what is unique across the whole Google Cloud namespace.
3. If you go to the Google Cloud console page, make sure that you work with that specific Project Id, enable the Dialogflow APIs and export the Service Account keys with the right permission.